# How to connect an old LG Optimus L5 2 cellphone screen to a Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: display, raspberry-pi, display-driver, mobile-phone, lg-monitor

I extracted the screen from an old LG Optimus L5 2 phone. The screen model is allegedly LM400MN1A.

I want to use it as a display for my Raspberry Pi 4B, but I don’t know which part of the board is the driver nor whether I can use it myself, and the end of the screen’s cable has a connector I can’t recognize, like a concave rectangular prism with about 24 pins.

Here are some pictures for reference:

The screen:
[image]

One side of the board (connection to the screen in the bottom-left corner):
[image]

The other side of the board:
[image]

Is this plausible?

Comment: I have 2 Pi 5s here and video is via HDMI.  That is how you get video. If your old monitor cannot use HDMI then get a newer monitor.

Comment: The thing is I need a really small capacitive monitor, and I’ve only found it in cellphones. That’s why I want to connect it. Besides, would an adapter to HDMI work? Although I don’t even know the connector type…

Comment: I do not know.  I use Eyoyo monitors for my Pi 5s and Eyoyo sells touch screen monitors that might help you.

Comment: While the Linux side of working with a Raspberry Pi is on topic here connecting random screens is heading far too much into the custom electronics side of things. Chances are you need some custom interface which first requires you to figure out the interface on the screen you have. I don't know if [raspberrypi.se] would accept this kind of question.